# Login with Facebook and Save details in database using blazor server

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I want to know how can I login with Facebook and save credentials details in my database for doing further processing in my website.

Currently i am using some code but in with I am only login to my site .

Comment: I'm pretty certain that you don't - that's the whole point of secure passwords.

Comment: Facebook or any similar authenticator won't let you grab that king of info